# How to resolve "This extension is not trusted by Enhanced Safe Browsing" warning?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

my extension named "Zypher" is available in chrome web store and some users started using it. I received the information from one user that the warning from chrome is as below:

**"This extension is not trusted by Enhanced Safe Browsing"** - witht the options "Continue to install" and "Close".

But, This is not the case for everyone. For others the warning is like "It can read and change your data on all websites".

I don't know Why it happens for specific users and how to fix this.

I have tried exploring the reasons but i could not find the result.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your first extension it may take a bit to be trusted.

[Here is a google article on it.](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?visit_id=638431154554655005-3050817726&rd=2#10745467&zippy=%2Cinstall-with-enhanced-safe-browsing)

I think this screenshot from the article answers your questions
[Article Screnshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMvYR.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).